# I am creating random accounts on brownie using accounts.add, are the account address "mine" even in the polygon-testnet?

Tags: private-key, brownie, polygon, account-generation

I am creating random accounts on brownie using accounts.add, are the account address "mine" even in the polygon-testnet? if so, how does brownie know that address is a new address. Also how to get the private key of the addresses, brownie only gives the mnemonic.

Answer (score 1):

i am not so clear on the " are the account address mine" part, but if you are using

```
accounts.add()
```

then, according to the [docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#Accounts.add), you are creating local accounts, meaning that they are stored locally in your system and [won't be available in the nodes](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#LocalAccount.save). To view the private key of these accounts, you can use the following code

```
account = accounts.add()
print(account.private_key)
```

You can, however, make these accounts "available" in the node by importing the account details. To do that, first, you need to [save the details of the account in a JSON file](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#LocalAccount.save)

```
account = accounts.add()
print(account.private_key)
account.save("new-account")
```

This will create a *new-account.json* file in your ***~/.brownie/accounts*** folder. Now, you can use a wallet like metamask to import this file (the *Import Account* option lies right below the *Create Account* option in metamask) and create a new account. You can then use that account with any given test/live network!

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey... i came to know, if you do accounts.add() in a testnet network, the account made is legit and can be found in etherscan, also you can do transactions (that will be reflected in node) using the private key the you got.

Comment: can you please share the details?